# Distribution of Norm of Two-Dimensional Brownian Motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am trying to solve the following:

Let $W_{t}=\left(W_{t}^{1},W_{t}^{2}\right)$ be a two dimensional Brownian motion.  Find the distribution of $$\|W_{t}\|=\sqrt{(W_{t}^{1})^2+(W_{t}^{2})^2}.$$

I know by the properties of Brownian motion for any $k \ge 1$ and $0<t_1<\dotsb<t_k$ the random vector $(W_{t_1},\dotsc,W_{t_k})$ is Gaussian with zero mean and covariance matrix $B(t_i,t_j)=\min(t_i,t_j).$  I also know that the sum of square iid Gaussian random variables $N(0,\sigma)$ is exponential with mean $2\sigma^2.$ Can I use this property to infer anything about the $L^2$ norm of a two-dimensional Brownian motion?

Comment: The first property you stated is about the "auto-correlation" of a one dimensional Brownian motion. The first thing you need to specify is that whether $W^1_t, W^2_t$ are independent. If they are independent, as you said, the sum of their square are follow a chi-square distribution (usually way to quote this result) with two-degrees of freedom. Of course it is a special case of the Gamma distribution, and when the degrees of freedom is 2, it is also an exponential distribution. So if you can directly apply this result, just go for it.

Comment: Yes I believe they are independent.  So I can claim that since $(W_{t_1},...,W_{t_k})$ is a gaussian random vector that the distribution of $||W_{t}||$ is $\chi^2(2)$ distributed by the above stated fact?  I don't have to fuss with the covariances at all?